# Console in PyDev not usable

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have the issue that the console view in recent Eclipse (Mars.2) will show when I open a Python file, but as soon as I run the interpreter the console view disappears and will not show again.

When calling the console view again, it flickers briefly at the position where it disappeared earlier, but it is basically not usable.

I am running Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) and PyDev in version: 1.0.0.7J--cLFtdL7E7AU7Q7QAAQg

The log file created when running the script can be found here: [log-file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BWp22z5qSxbGgyc1pLakstd3M)

How do I get the console to work?

Answer (score 0):

From the log, it seems a bug in Eclipse itself... try updating to Eclipse Neon (it's currently in RC phase and should be pretty stable already).

Comment: Thanks for the note on Neon, but it doesn't change anything in the behavior of Eclipse.